# Python decorators for classes to include class identity

Tags: python, python-decorators, metaclass

Basically I have a Base class and a metaclass and a ton of classes that use both
I want to avoid doing `class Name(Base, metaclass=Meta)` over and over again and instead do this

```
@deco
class Name:
```

I already have a decorator like this:

```py
def deco(cls):
    return Meta(cls.__name__, (Base, cls), dict(vars(cls)))
```

and it *works*, the problem is that its erasing the identity of the original class, for example:

- when hovering over a variable of that class, vscode says its a `_class_Meta` object and not a `Name` object
- `print(Name().__doc__)` works as expected but hovering over said objects doesn't show any docstring
- functions and variables of the `Name` and the `Base` classes are not even recognized by vscode at all, only attributes of the metaclass

Im basically looking for something like the functools.wraps decorator

Comment: well, this is due to the tooling (in this case, VSCode), relies on static analysis of the code for its inferences. You are using  Python dynamic capabilities, and the static tools simply do not catch up. It is worth opening an issue ticket with the tools you use, so they can develop better support for these cases (if there are people interested in doing so).

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new base class with `Base` as the base class and `Meta` as the metaclass, so other classes can inherit from the new base class instead:

```
class Meta(type):
    def __call__(cls):
        print('new instance')
        return super().__call__()

class Base:
    def __init__(self):
        print('base')

class NewBase(Base, metaclass=Meta):
    pass

class Name(NewBase):
    pass

print(Name())
```

This outputs:

```
new instance
base
<__main__.Name object at 0x1467a61a4b80>
```

Demo: https://ideone.com/UOfMzv

Comment: yes, this will satisfy both runtime and the static tools, and it is the "There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it." from the start.

Answer (score 0):

**Why this is happening and why you shouldn't do this in the first place:**
You are getting no docstrings from vscode since this is quite hacky and thus vscode doesn't understand it, because it's very unpythonic, so it can't show you corect tooltips.
Always remember: `Explicit is better than implicit.` - The Zen of Python (read it yourself: `import this`). And it's not even worth it, it just makes your code more complex and less readable/understandable, and yes, even for yourself.